# Running file from batch file

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I am working in Windows 10.

This is my code saved in .bat file:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

"c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"
```

If I open Command Prompt (cmd) manually and execute each line everything works fine. But if I execute .bat file with content above, first line executes fine but second line just changes current folder to `c:\Arch\` folder and `Upload from DB to Redcap.py` file is not executed.  How to fix my code so second line of my code execute `Upload from DB to Redcap.py` file that is located at `c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py` ?

Comment: Maybe the first command started a new instance of cmd within cmd, if you type exit then it might continue with the second line.. which isn't what you want.  You can try 'start' in the manner suggested.. or for calling a bat file you can use `call` i.e.  `call blah.bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `cmd /keep vs cmd /continue`

If you are using `/k`, and you don't need quotes, until you type `exit` command, the next command on the `bat/cmd` will never be executed.

You started a `cmd /keep` "interpreter" and did not leave/exit/close it, only after this that your next command will be executed...

When you use the terminal by opening a new interpreter by typing 'cmd /k', it works because you are interacting directly with it, in this case in bat, onli line that work is: `cmd /k "...\enable.bat"`, the bat file in command is also executed because it is on the same line.

In the bat, `cmd / k somefile.bat [or] some command` it will start a new interpreter and keep it open for input until the moment you type exit or close the current cmd window. Otherwise, it will stay waiting for you to insert one or more commands to execute them, and in the code, the next execution is on the next line:
  ("C:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"), it will never run unless you type it for this current interpreter, or type `exit` to quit and return to previous interpreter run you next line command.

Try replace with `cmd /c` and your interpreter will goon execute your code line by line...

But I think it’s not even a `cmd` call running his `bat/cmd`.

---

The command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) will execute your `bat`/`cmd` just by executing or, when you click on it, there is no need to add a specific instruction to execute your `bat` script.

Save this code below as file.bat and try:

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3" 
call .\Scripts\Activate.bat "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3" 

py "c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"
```

In addition, if you are using in one `bat` file to to execute another `bat`file, so use `call c:\file.bat`...

[√] **[cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

[√] **[cmd /MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)**

[√] **[How to run multiple bat files within a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)**

Comment: Thank you. Your code worked after I replace `py "c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"` with `python "c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"`

Comment: Also thank you for good explanation. This is very helpful!

Comment: @vasili111 Thank you too, good to know that work

Comment: @vasili111 If you have official distro from Python, then py will be in c:\windows\system32... see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)

Comment: No `py` file in `C:\windows\system32` or `c:\windows\`. I have Python from Anaconda installation. It seams Anaconda does not have Python Launcher for Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794388/1601703  But at that link and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861943/how-to-install-python-launcher are ways to install it. Thank you very much for that information I did not knew about Python Launcher for Windows.

Comment: @vasili111 Take a time to read this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471933/how-to-run-a-python-program-in-windows-10-command-prompt/60479607#60479607)**

Comment: Thank you! Very good tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

If python.exe is in your `PATH`, you could try to prepend `python.exe` to the offending line:

```
python.exe "c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"
```

Another option is to use the `start` command:

```
start /b "" "c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"
```

`/b` tells `start` not to open a new `cmd` window, and `""` is to avoid it interpreting `"c:\Arch\Upload from DB to Redcap.py"` as a title.